# Regex comma delimited, no comma at the end of the string, no comma at the end with single params

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to validate a string with a regexp comma delimited.
No problem in getting this point...

```
preg_match("/^[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]$/", 'str1,str2,str3')
```

It works properly on strings as above.
However, this doesn't work in cases like

```
preg_match("/^[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]$/", 'str1')
```

How can I validate also that case? Is there a way to do it or I need to do it in 2 steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches both `str1,str2,str3` and `str1`

```
^(?:[^, ]+?,?)+?$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ4tD8/3)

**UPDATE**

```
^(?:\w+,?)+?$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ4tD8/5)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. :) The problem is that if i put dots "." or whatever you want, it's still matched.
This ´str1,str2,str3´ shouldn't be good

Comment: @RobertoRizzi I'm not sure I follow. Should `str1,str2,str3` be matched or not? Could you provide more examples?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to validate a string with a regexp comma delimited.

```
preg_match('/^[^,\s]+(?:,[^,\s]+)*$/', 'str1');
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qV3lS6/4)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. :) The problem is that if i put dots "." or whatever you want, it's still matched.
This ´str1,str2,str3´ shouldn't be good